# Rotisserie spit ,iron rod?

Tags: food-safety

Is it OK use a plain iron rod for a Rotisserie spit?

I have a solid piece of iron rod that is about 1/4 inch diameter and from what I can see it has no coatings. It just looks like extruded iron.

Could this be used as a spit safely? Or should I be using stainless steel?

Comment: My guess is that the answer will have to be "maybe". There are probably entertaining flavors of iron/steel that would poison meat that was cooked on it. Also, steeping iron in hot liquid will likely rust it quickly.

Comment: I would personally put it in the fire first to bake off any unseen coatings ... then rub it with oil and attempt to season it like a cast iron pan.  Your big problem is going to be making sure the food rotates with the rod, rather than staying there while the rod spins inside it.

Comment: This may seem obvious, but make sure it has a square or blade cross-section. If it's round, especially if it's deployed horizontally, there's every chance, after some cooking time,  that the spit will turn, but the roast won't.

Answer (score 1):

Stainless steel wasn't invented until 1913. Plain iron then plain steel was used for cooking spits for over 3,000 years and for quite some time after 1913.

It is highly likely that it is safe to use as a spit

Comment: Hi, Cynetta. Welcome to Seasoned Advice. You can take the tour [over here.](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/tour) To make an answer definitive, perhaps give a reason for exactly why/when it would be safe..ie.. scrub off any rust/flecks and sanitize.. This will make answer seem less like an opinion.